# Check for consecutive condition in sas

Tags: sas

```
 DATA have;
    input month 1-2 name $ 5-9 spending $ 12-13 ;
    cards;
1   Simon  2
2   Simon  2
3   Simon  3
4   Simon  5
5   Simon  0
6   Simon  1
7   Simon  0
8   Simon  0
9   Simon  0
10  Simon  0
11  Simon  0
12  Simon  0
1   John   3
2   John   3
3   John   3
4   John   5
5   John   0
6   John   0
7   John   0
8   John   0
9   John   0
10  John   0
11  John   1
12  John   0
;
RUN;
```

How can i check for 6 consecutive "0" ? 
if spending has morethan 5 and next consecutive 6 spending is "0" then i need to tag it as 0 at the end of 6th month. 
Should i use retain or arrays , please help ? 
below is how i want the new column to be ..

```
 DATA want;
    input month 1-2 name $ 5-9 spending  12-13 tag 14-15;
    cards;
1   Simon  2 0
2   Simon  2 0
3   Simon  4 0
4   Simon  5 1
5   Simon  0 1
6   Simon  1 1
7   Simon  0 1
8   Simon  0 1
9   Simon  0 1
10  Simon  0 1
11  Simon  0 1
12  Simon  0 0
1   John   3 0
2   John   3 0
3   John   3 0
4   John   5 1
5   John   0 1
6   John   0 1
7   John   0 1
8   John   0 1
9   John   0 1
10  John   0 0
11  John   1 0
12  John   0 0
;
RUN;
```

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your question and logic here.  Can you rephrase your question to make it more clearer?  (e.g. spending is never above 5 in a given month, yet your condition says spending more than 5; where does 6 consecutive zeros come into this?)

Comment: Your `want` dataset is not consistent with your requirements. E.g. for simon in month 5, spending is not greater than 5, and one of the next 6 months has spending = 1, so simon should always have tag = 0. Please think carefully about your requirements, have a go at solving this yourself and correct your want dataset.